# deleting a secondary branch after merging into a master branch- will all contributions stay?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

If there is a main repo by an organization. That repo might have a master and a secondary branch. Say, few contributors contribute to the secondary repo over the period of one month, on an average of 2 to 3 commits everyday. Their commits count since they are sending a pull request to a secondary branch of a master project. But, if the author of the main project, plans to delete the secondary branch after pushing all commits to the master, will all the contributions stay as it is? or since the secondary branch is deleted, all contributions go off?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the contributions won't go off/be deleted, since everything that was done on the side branch has been pushed (and thus taken over) to the master branch.

A side branch is just a (good and safe way) to keep the original and working code unchanged, so if anything happens that would kill the whole program, the changes won't affect the master branch. If the version on the side branch works, it can be pushed to the master branch, and the side branch safely deleted (since, as said before, the changes made to the side branch went to the master branch). The contributions are independent from the branch.

Answer (score 0):

If contributions to second branch will be merged (included) to main branch you can securely delete second branch even though it will have same (similar) commits to master branch.

What you should take into account are commit hashes - if two commits introduce same changes and has same commit message but are on different branches then they will have different hashes and as such deletion of one wouldn't affect the other.

It is because hash of commit is calculated not only from commit messages and commit itself but also from previous commits (if you change something in earlier (parent) commit it will change hashes of all commits deriving from it (children), eg. when you do `git rebase`).

So merging / applying commit from one branch to another effectively creates new commit (meaning new hash) on target branch independent of source commit.

Here are some good resources to understand git a little bit more:
https://wildlyinaccurate.com/a-hackers-guide-to-git
http://think-like-a-git.net (this is the one to start with)